# Crash app when call setUnselectedItemTintColor from UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I've tried both line bellow but it all cause **[UITabBar setUnselectedItemTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

```
[self.tabBar setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: In Quick Help tab, it shown 
`Availibility: iOS (10.0 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later)`.
What is the number iOS version in your device?

Comment: I used a iOS 9.0 device to test. Anw, I found an answer bellow.

Comment: then you should accept the answer. @JaredChu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method is available on iOS 10 only, so it will crash on previous versions. You should check method availability before calling it.

```
 if ([[UITabBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setUnselectedItemTintColor:)]) {
     [[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for iOS 9.0 devices? Because your code will not works with it.

Comment: @JaredChu Check this solution for older iOS versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18433996/1689376

Comment: I found that the following answer works better as the appearance proxy is unreliable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504304/respondstoselector-fails-for-appearance-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if ([[UITabBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setUnselectedItemTintColor:)]) 
    {
        [[UITabBar appearance]setUnselectedItemTintColor:AppYellowColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AppYellowColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```